# VS 2010 Flag a Method to not be stepped into on debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a program that has several small methods (such as printing a line to the console for tracing, getter queries, etc).

Is there a way to flag these so when I'm stepping through debugging I don't enter these methods? (outside of setting breakpoints after each and every one)

Comment: Give the method the [DebuggerStepThrough] attribute.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid stepping into the method with the following combination

- Annotate the method with `[DebuggerNonUserCode]`
- Ensure Just My Code Debugging is enabled.

The second is default for most Visual Studio profiles.  You can verify though by doing the following

- Tools -> Options
- Navigate to Debugger
- Ensure "Enable Just My Code" is checked

Answer (score 0):

You can use F10  or the 'step over' button on the debug toolbox to step-over methods while you're debugging.  This will prevent you from entering these methods unless an exception is thrown or you have a breakpoint inside of them.